# NSIS and PATH env variables

Tags: nsis

In my installer, I embed cmake and others installers.
During installation the user install, through my installer, cmake and add cmake to the path.

At this point if I open a command prompt and type cmake, it is actually recognized.

But in the installer I run the following command:

```
ReadEnvStr $1 %COMSPEC%
ExecWait '"$1" /c cmake XXX'
```

But it tells me cmake isn't recognized. How is that possible? I just open a command prompt before in c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe and type cmake and it was recognized so why this code does not work?

It is like the paths env variables was not updated somehow. Of course if I reboot it works fine but I would like to avoid it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are inherited from their parent process by default. Explorer.exe is the only application that listens for environment changes and therefore if you start a new process from the start menu it will run with the updated environment.

You can update the installer process environment and it will be passed to the ExecWait child:

```
System::Call 'kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "foo", t "bar")'
```

When dealing with long path strings you really should be using the [EnvVar plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/EnVar_plug-in).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You made it very clear. The solutions works for me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I am using maven for downloading the nsis zip and using in my java project. How can i add a new nsis plugin into this. Maven as below <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.nullsoft.nsis</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>nsis</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.46</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/nsis</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>

Comment: @JDGuide This question is about run-time, not configuring the compiler. I don't know anything about Maven.